# Browser Stuck on Opening URL

Tags: browser, virus

All,
On my desktop and laptop for the past three days at some point in the morning (between 10am-11am) all my browsers have been "taken over" by something.  Whenever I open either Chrome, IE, or Firefox,  the opening URL is what I'm stuck on.  If I try to navigate to any other URL it immediately takes me back to that starting URL.  When I turn on Fiddler, I can see my attempt to navigate to a new URL going out and a normal 200 HTTP response coming back but once the browser tries to render that page it immediately reverts back to the original starting URL.

The problem does not happen if I go into Safe Mode with Networking. So, is it likely that a virus has infected all three of my browser simultaneously or is it more likely that some common service that they all use is infected/broken? Should I start by reinstalling each browser or is that futile?

This certainly smells like a virus but I've done a Norton full scan (while in safe mode) and it didn't find anything.  I haven't been able to find anyone articles with people experiencing the same behavior so I have no idea how to diagnose it or solve it.

Please Help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is not a problem with your computer but your ISP. I mean, the gateway which connects you to the internet, because it happens on both your machines and it is happening on different browsers.

However, this question does not seem to be related to programming.

Comment: Yes, I talked with my ISP and router vendors and went through a complete reset in each of those tiers but the problem came back.  And you're right, this isn't a programming problem but my software development is at a grinding halt and I thought my fellow developers could sympathize and maybe someone is experiencing the same problem.  If no one cares to help me on this one I understand.  I just don't know what to do, Google results provide no help.